# findByUsername or find method of Facade absract class

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, design-patterns, facade

I'm trying to make a Login app with `JSF`, and I found in forums that a lot of people use `LoginByUsername`(or findByUsername or whatever they call it ,anyway a method that does find the username and returns the user and uses SQL)  and they put it in the facade(session bean for entity class) ! 
But the facade itself gives us something called `find(Object id)` ,and the id is username . 
so what's better : using find or making its own method(that uses SQL)? and why?

thanks in advance for your help

Comment: `But the facade itself gives us something ..` What facade do you mean?

Comment: i have a facade called UsersFacade and it extends from abstarct facade .
abstarct facade is an abstract class that gives all the methods for persitence in my database such as : create , remove , ect...

Comment: if i want to put something in the data base , i can do : 
 `UsersFacade.create(user); `

Comment: Then why should the problem be JSF related? You should narrow it to a more concrete question.

Comment: i corrected the tag , facade is related to design patterns so i added the right tags , thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `username` is used as `id` in your app, then it's no need to write a new method `LoginByUsername`/`findByUsername`, since you have already have the method `find(Object id)`, which can achieve the function `findByUsername` will do.

But, since it's a **Login App**, i think it's better to provide a method called `findByUserAndPassword`, and if no result is returned, tell the user that **user or password is wrong**, which it's **commonly used** in many website.